# "Нестатическая ссылка на член должна указываться относительно заданного объекта"

Tags: c++, массивы, классы

Никак не могу понять, что я делаю не так, когда я хочу написать размерность массива как `bitsize`. Когда пишу `массив[8]` ошибки нет, но при `массив[bitsize]` появляется ошибка:

> "Нестатическая ссылка на член должна указываться относительно
>   заданного объекта"

/ Уже весь интернет просмотрел и ничего не нашел, помогите пожалуйста, как исправить это?

```
Сlass BinaryTransformation  {   //класс для работы с двоичными числами
private:

 int newNum1, newNum2;
 const int bitsize = 8;
 int bits1[bitsize];

 public:

Calculate value, value1;

void getNewNum(Calculate x, Calculate y) 
{
    newNum1 = x.getValue();
    newNum2 = y.getValue1();
    cout << "newNum1 = " << newNum1 << endl;
    cout << "NewNum2 = " << newNum2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: `static const int bitsize = 8;`

Answer (score 2):

У Вас `bitsize` - нестатическая константа, она каждая своя для каждого экземпляра класса.

Поэтому компилятору непонятно, какую выбирать. Как вариант, можете сделать константу статической: `static const int bitsize = 8;` - вот так. Такая константа будет одинакова для всех экземпляров класса и обращаться к ней извне можно  `BinaryTransformation::bitsize`.

Comment: Работает! Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из диагностики могу предположить что возможно стоит this->bitsize написать вместо bitsize. Детальнее можно посмотреть если все же код места, на которое диагностика, будет приведен, а не русское слово массив.